# MySQL - multiple conditions

Tags: mysql, group-by, sum, left-join, window-functions

I have two tables: orders, shops.

shops:

```
shop_id | name 
-----------------------
20      | PizzaShop
34      | SushiShop
```

orders:

```
orders_id | creation_time       | user_id | shop_id | Status
------------------------------------------------------------------
1         | 2021-01-01 14:00:00 | 1       | 20      | OK
2         | 2021-02-01 14:00:00 | 1       | 34      | Cancelled
3         | 2021-03-01 14:00:00 | 1       | 20      | OK
4         | 2021-04-01 14:00:00 | 1       | 34      | OK
5         | 2021-05-01 14:00:00 | 2       | 20      | OK
6         | 2021-06-01 14:00:00 | 2       | 20      | OK
7         | 2021-07-01 14:00:00 | 2       | 34      | OK
8         | 2021-08-01 14:00:00 | 2       | 34      | OK
```

I need to find the "favourite" shop of every user, knowing that the favourite is the one that has more "OK" orders, and **if there are two shops with the same amount of orders**, then select the one that has the most recent order.

The result should be something like this:

```
user_id | total_number_OK_orders | favourite_shop_name 
------------------------------------------------------------------
1       | 3                      | PizzaShop
2       | 4                      | SushiShop
```

I have no idea how to do the second column. For the first this is what I have for the moment:

```
SELECT 
    orders.user_id,
    SUM(if(orders.Status = 'OK', 1, 0)) AS total_number_OK_orders
FROM orders
LEFT JOIN shops
    ON orders.shop_id = shops.shop_id
GROUP BY orders.user_id;
```

Comment: What is your version of MySql?

Comment: You have already asked this question.

Comment: @Shadow I don't know if the requirement of this question has been answered before, but for sure your proposed duplicate link does not provide a full solution.

Comment: @forpas I disagree, the duplicate question is about getting the max of counts per group, which is exactly this question is about. The OP managed to get the simple conditional counting, so that does not require separate answer.

Comment: @Shadow this question is about the total number of counts and not only the max. The max number of counts is used only to join to the other table to get the shop's name.

Comment: @forpas no, this question is about getting the shop per user with the most counts where the status is OK. That's exactly what the other question is about, just the other question is about age and level, not about user and shop.

Comment: @Shadow take a look at the expected results: 3 and 4 are the total number of orders for each user and not the number of orders in the shop where they placed the most orders.

Comment: @forpas correct. The problem is that the OP solved that one - it is in the question! The OP does not know how to get the favourite shop name, which is determined by max count of OKs per shop per customer (`I need to find the "favourite" shop of every user, knowing that the favourite is the one that has more "OK" orders`). Which is answered in the other question already.

Comment: @Shadow the question is not *how to find the favourite shop of each user*. This would make it a duplicate of many questions. The question is how to combine 2 different results in the same query, one of which is *how to find the favourite shop of each user*. If 1 of the results (or both) are solved, this does not mean that their combination is also solved.

Comment: @forpas This is not what the OP asked. The question was about the 2nd column only.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For MySql 8.0+ you can use window functions `SUM()` and `FIRST_VALUE()`:

```
SELECT DISTINCT o.user_id, 
       SUM(SUM(o.Status = 'OK')) OVER (PARTITION BY o.user_id) total_number_OK_orders,
       FIRST_VALUE(s.name) OVER (PARTITION BY o.user_id ORDER BY SUM(o.Status = 'OK') DESC, MAX(o.creation_time) DESC) favourite_shop_name 
FROM orders o LEFT JOIN shops s
ON s.shop_id = o.shop_id AND o.Status = 'OK'
GROUP BY o.user_id, s.shop_id;
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=69a72a2bdb1eed22fd42bf4b4f7727e5).